# Yad P'shutta For Free Online

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, rambam, rav-nachum-rabinovitch

Is R. Rabinovich's Yad P'shutta on the Mishne Torah available for free online?

---

I already noted the commentary to Hil. T'shuva on HebrewBooks.

Comment: @loewian Do we actually need a Rav Nachum Rabinovitch tag? He probably does not have more related questions than Rav Kafah, Rav Moshe, Rav Shlomo Zalman, Rav Elyashi, Rav Bentziyon Abba Shaul, Rav Ovadiah, etc. I dont think all of them have their own tags...

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/moshe-feinstein/info http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacham-ovadia-yosef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not available for free online. However, it is available in entirety on [otzar hachochmah](http://otzar.org) (which allows free preview of the first 40 pages of each volume).